# Resigned due to hostile work environment. Can I collect unemployment benefits?

Tags: resignation, united-states

I recently resigned from my job due to being in a hostility environment towards me.

The Medical Doctor I assisted called me names such as; stupid, I don't need you and that I was a snitch. She called me a snitch because when a problem would arise; I would go to the Director on the floor I worked on. She would simply tell me to "deal with it". The Medical Doctor I was assisting would not talk to me for months, she would throw charts at me in my office. We worked together for 2 years and since then she consistently harassed me and I tried to hang in there. The Director threatened me not to go to HR because she stated what happens on this floor stays on this floor. So I had no help in my situation. It was difficult to go to work being that I would have to deal with her name calling and being called a snitch because I was doing the right thing by going to the Director so we can come up with a solution, but with no success.

I filed for unemployment and I'm not sure if I will receive it for this particular case.

I was just wondering if anybody had any insight on a situation about whether unemployment would accept this reason for resigning.

What are the guidelines that the government will use to determine my eligibility?  Is there anything I can do to improve my chances now?

**UPDATE** I received my unemployment

Comment: Folks do tend to overuse downvotes when comments, vote-to-close, or flagging would be more appropriate responses...

Comment: Just because she said not to go to HR isn't a reason you shouldn't have gone to HR in lieu of resigning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was just wondering if anybody had any insight on a situation about
>   whether unemployment would accept this reason for resigning.

In most states you would be disqualified from receiving Unemployment Benefits if you quit without good cause attributable to your employment. Your situation may or may not be considered "good cause".

Look at your state's Unemployment Benefits website to see what the specific laws of your state say. If you are in New York, see: https://www.labor.ny.gov/ui/claimantinfo/beforeyouapplyfaq.shtm

In most locales, you need to be actively seeking work to be eligible for benefits. I always recommend that you find your next job before you quit your current job, but sometimes conditions are intolerable. Make sure you look for work now. If you are eligible for benefits, you will likely have to prove that you are looking. In my state, you have to periodically provide evidence.

Nobody here can adjudicate this for you - it would only be guessing. The case will depend on your state laws, and what you and your former employer say to the Unemployment board.

You'll need to wait a few weeks to see if your claim is denied. If it is, you'll have an appeal process.