# When should I ask as an intern for possibility of a full time offer?

Tags: internship

I'm currently doing an internship at a place for around half a year, I've been part timing during the semester and working full time during the summer.

I've been given more responsibilities as time went on and have greater access to things (I work in a tech related field). I believe this means that they plan to keep me for the long haul, but I'm not sure if it directly translates to a full time job.

Right now I'm a senior with 2 semesters of college left, is it too early to ask for the possibility of a full time job?

Comment: Does your internship have an end date? Also despite having stilla year in college left, are you willing to go full-time?

Answer (score 4):

I've been in a similar position to this as not being told what happens next however I had already enquired about it.

Basically, if you're willing to take a full time post when you finish your internship then just ask.

**DON'T** directly ask for a job, just say something along the lines of (can be adjusted to suit you)

> Hey "x", I've been wondering recently as it's coming to the end of my college year what my future here holds. Will I be potentially be getting kept on and if no what will happen to my work, do I just leave it at a point to pass it on?

This makes it seem you haven't already assumed you're getting the job but you're also willing to prepare your work for the next person (if need be). Also shows that you're being prepared so it may or may not add to your credibility when potentially securing the full time post.

> is it too early to ask

Not at all, in fact theres not long left at all now would be perfect timing to do so as you'll be leaving yourself ample time to apply for a new job elsewhere should the answer to your question be negative. As well as this if the answer is no - it's not all bad, you'll still have an internship when applying for jobs which will help you in the long run when applying for other jobs as explained [Here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/108260/is-it-easier-to-get-a-job-when-you-already-have-one)

Answer (score 3):

Now is a good time. I'd suggest speaking with your boss along these lines:

> > Hi **_, I have really enjoyed working here at**  over the past  **months, and I would like to continue working here after I finish my education in _** months. That said, on-campus recruiting has begun and if a full time opportunity with *company* isn't in the cards, I will need to begin recruiting for other full-time opportunities. So I wanted to reach out to you to ask if you could help me understand how you're thinking about the potential for me to get a full-time position with *company*.

If the answer you get isn't fully satisfactory, or they try to push off the decision to some later date, I *strongly strongly* recommend that you be candid with them that you cannot wait for long. Something like:

> > Thanks for listening, and I hope we can get a decision soon. In the meantime, I'm going to have to at least begin recruiting for other companies, just so I don't miss the opportunity that I'll need to have a job lined up for post-graduation. In order to support that, I have two requests for you: (1) would you be willing to take some time to provide me with feedback I can use to improve myself for future full-time positions? and (2) would you be willing to serve as a reference for me if I receive a request from a potential employer for references? Again, my hope is to work with you at *company* after graduation, so I hope this all ends up not being needed, but I have to play it safe until I know for sure that I have an offer I can accept!

Good luck to you and congrats on finding a company you like! That's a big part of the battle!