# My employer will not have required permits to employ me in the future. How should I approach job search?

Tags: job-search, manager, visa

I'm currently legally working for a US company on a special permit, I'm not a US citizen. My permit will expire this year in a few months. I'm allowed to apply for a renewal, but I learned that this will require my employer to have a certain permit code. This is a code that I did *not* require for my current status, but one I need only to renew it. The HR Department of my current employer told me they do not currently have this code, but they are actively trying hard to get it and apparently it's their priority. I'm really happy in my current employer and I want to give them a chance to get this permit code (as they claimed they will be able to get it before my deadline, **but no promises**).

In order to increase my chances of being employed in US after my current permit expires (i.e. to renew it), I plan to go on a job hunt and specifically choose a company that has this permit code (it's supposed to be an easy thing most US companies have, I don't know why my employer is having a problem, having said this I have exactly no idea what is the process to get this code). However, there are a few complications and I unfortunately, I do not have a friend or attorney that can help me, so I have these questions:

- Should I share this concern with my manager? Currently only HR knows, not my manager. I do not want to be fired right now just because my immigration status is wacky. I have a very good relationship with my manager and he has "big plans" with me (and I recently received a huge and generous bonus).
- What's the best way to filter companies that match my criteria? Is this something I can straight-up ask in an initial screening? I do not want to come off needy or "weird", so to say, but I guess companies understand that employing non-citizens do require special complications.

I'm a little time pressured. Not too pressured, I still have a couple months to find a new employer and apply for a renewal; but I'm wondering if it makes sense to quit my job now and focus on job hunting.

I'm a salaried, high-skilled worker. I intentionally chose not to share any more information for my own anonymity. **For my anonymity, please do not share any more information even if you can infer it from this post.**

Comment: If HR is working hard to keep you, and your manager has plans for you, why do you think your manager would want to fire you?

Comment: @DarkCygnus not sure what you mean by "contract". I'm an at-will worker. Had this complications wouldn't happen, I would continue working in this company normally indefinitely (as long as US Immigration Services let me). I'm planning to job-hunt now, because if I can be employed by a company with this permit code, I can apply for a renewal; otherwise I cannot apply for renewal and need to leave USA once my permit expires (in a few months).

Comment: @thursdaysgeek I don't know, it's always a possibility I suppose.

Comment: @user3241118408 what I meant was, are you sure you will be terminated soon? Or are you worried more of the permit and stuff, and that not renewing it will "force" you to search for another job that can get you one?

Comment: Which "permit code" is this

Comment: @JoeStrazzere this is a startup, we didn't even have HR until a month or so ago. There isn't much "politics" and everything works in a very informal way, so I wouldn't be surprised if my manager didn't know. Regardless, it seems likely I should mention this to my manager in person (instead of him learning from HR) and maybe ask for his help to press HR further to get this permit number (as DarkCygnus's answer). Do you agree?

Comment: @Neuromancer unfortunately, I do not want to answer that question. Does this change the answer in any way? This is supposed to be something "most" US companies have and something they can get quickly. As I said, I do not know the details, and *why* my company wasn't able to get this quickly (HR does not share this information) but they told me they are trying to get it and they said it's realistic to get it sooner or later.

Comment: @user3241118408 well the different visas / permits have different rules   and its bit unclear why your current employer can not get this permit when another employer can?

Comment: @Neuromancer that is unclear to me too. As I said, HR claims this is a code they would "normally be capable of" getting but due to a problem they haven't been able to get it until now but are still trying. This is as much as I know. My immigration advisor told me this should be something very easy to get so I'm guessing I can find another company that has this. Again, a lot of question marks at this point.

Comment: State your situation at the top of your resume and send it out

Comment: UPDATE: Turns out my employer has this code. It's all good now. Talking to my manager was the right thing to do, the problem immediately escalated and got fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> but I'm wondering if it makes sense to quit my job now and focus on job hunting.

No, doing that is not something I would recommend.

It's always better (as for higher chances) to job-hunt while still employed, so I suggest you start searching for a new job right now while you still have this current job (check [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/108260/73791) and [this other](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/22888/73791) posts that explains why)

> What's the best way to filter companies that match my criteria? Is this something I can straight-up ask in an initial screening?

Yes, it is fine to ask that, as it is a highly relevant and normal aspect to consider in order for you to be able to work on US as a non-citizen.

Instead of trying to "filter" companies beforehand, I suggest you seek those you like, apply, and during the first exchanges simply mention that you would require a work permit, and if they would need anything from you to obtain such permit. In case some companies can't provide such permits then you can proceed to discard such option(s).

> Should I share this concern with my manager?

Yes, it would make sense to share this with your manager if it is something you are worried about. Not only for the chance that your manager could obtain this code faster (or work along HR to make this swiftly), but also so you keep them up-to-date and take any steps they consider adequate here.