# On a job interview, should you mention that you've quit your job two days ago?

Tags: interviewing, resignation

For the last year I've been working as a software developer at a company whose culture started to get too much to handle psychologically. That's why I decided that it's time to move on.

I gave my notice two weeks ago and will be leaving the company during this week. I've no guaranteed job offer from different company, but I have just enough funds to keep me on my feet for the next 4-5 months.

Because my resume continuted to circulate on the job market, I already have a few scheduled interviews for different companies during next week. They all have seen my resume and know that I work at my current company. But by the time the  interview-day arrives, I will be unemployed for 2-3 days.

How should I handle answering questions related 'to my current employer'? Should I tell that I've resigned three days ago? If not, how should I escape giving 100% honest answer if asked about the company I left few days ago?

Comment: Related: [Why is quitting without having a new job lined up seen so negatively by employers?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/22888)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't volunteer the information.  IF they ask, and you've not yet served out your notice period, you can tell them something along the lines of that you're looking for growth, and you've gone as far as you can in this job.

If they don't ask, don't tell them.  They may ask why you're interested in leaving your current employer (which is more likely), so you can say "I am leaving because I'm looking for professional growth".

Answer (score 4):

> How should I handle answering questions related 'to my current employer'?

Honestly.

> Should I tell that I've resigned three days ago?

Yes.

That's the easy part.

Of course, the next thing they're going to want to know is why. Unfortunately, that's the hard part. If you say that you didn't want to work at a...

> company whose culture started to get too much to handle psychologically

that's just going to create even more uncomfortable questions - or it's going to leave them with the impression that it's just you, who can't get along with others well, and the company wasn't at fault.

Comment: Amen brother...

Comment: "reasons for leaving" is a very difficult thing to discuss in an interview because it's really easy for a candidate to either deliberately cover up their own issues, or unintentionally project those issues on the company. It's really best to not have to discuss this subject, which is why people say it's best to not leave your current job before you have a new offer - even if (you think) you've done nothing wrong, and you have enough money to live off of, it leaves you at a huge risk when interviewing.

Comment: If you tell them why you left, be prepared to tell them why it will be different if they hire you. The company interviewing you doesn't want to hire you if they think they will be another "company whose culture started to get too much to handle psychologically." They will need assurance that you aren't just going to leave them for the same reasons.

Comment: Yes, that's good advice. It's always better to show you can understand a challenge and make a reasonable change to overcome it, versus just blaming it on someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as they're probably going to find out anyways, and it's better to hear it coming from you with reasons they will accept then finding out through their own research and thinking you had something to hide by not telling them.

Also quitting a job without having the next one is a pretty risky move, so I hope your reasons for leaving are rock-solid.

Comment: Telling them is okay, but I'm not sure how the right answer would sound like. I definitely don't want to paint my last company in a negative light.