# Can i change my Job field

Tags: software-industry, new-job, job-change, career-switch

I am currently working as Software Developer(1.4 years of exp) in Data Science field for a MNC company in India and my current role is Data Scientist for a client project.

I don't like this project as it is a support one and there is nothing to learn in terms of Data Science except for the support. I just joined this company like 2 months ago and started disliking it. Meanwhile I have an offer from a very good company in Singapore where the designation is "Program coordinator and Analyst".

I am in a confusion whether to leave this Data Science field and accept the offer from Singapore. As Everyone knows Data Science is emerging and the fastest growing field everywhere. But I don't like the company or job responsibilities I am having now (I am getting paid low as well).

If I change, What will be the consequences? I see many people are constantly looking for data science. And i am getting a thought that i shouldn't change it. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I change, What will be the consequences?

I would strongly advise you **not to take such relevant decisions based on some fancy job title solely.**

Job titles vary *much*, and not necessarily specify what the role actually involves doing; as far as you know this new job could be even less appealing to you.

I suggest that if you are interested in that new offer try to *get more information on the role first*, so you can weight the pros and cons to make a proper decision (salary, projects involved, living cost in the area, and so on). This you can find during interviews and other exchanges of information. After this, you will be able to see what the *consequences* may be and if they are ok with you.

As a side suggestion, it is better for you if you [secure the job while still employed](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22888/why-is-quitting-without-having-a-new-job-lined-up-seen-so-negatively-by-employer).