# Applying for a different job in the company I've handed in my notice to?

Tags: job-change, resignation

I've been employed in a UX position and I found out that this wasn't for me and I am pursuing work that is more front-end and coding-related. So i handed in my notice at the company, since I became very unhappy. I've not got a new job offer yet at a new company.

The development manager asked me about it and when I said I was looking for something within development she seemed to react to the fact that I hadn't asked her. I've since learned that she is in fact looking for developers.

What are the disadvantages or pitfalls in applying for these positions?
At this point pretty much every one in the company has gotten word that I have handed in my notice, and I am set to leave this company at the end of next month.

Comment: Why would you voluntarily leave a job before you secured another?

Comment: is `The development manager` is the one you report to?

Comment: Is your unhappiness purely down to the work you are doing?  What is the culture like in the development team?

Comment: Thank you for your questions. The reason I chose to leave my position before securing another is that it was starting to affect my physical healthy. With Regards to reporting, my direct supervisor is in a different position related to UX. I am fairly certain that it is the work that I am doing that made me choose to hand in my resignation.

Comment: Related: [Is it really that bad to leave my job as a software engineer before I have an offer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/54480) and [Why is quitting without having a new job lined up seen so negatively by employers?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/22888)

Comment: @user1666620 to be in control, maybe?

Comment: @mathreadler to be in control of what exactly? You give yourself a hard deadline with no backup plan other than impending unemployment and having to spend your savings to survive. Then you have to explain to potential employers why it is you decided to voluntarily make yourself unemployed. It just screams of impulsiveness.

Comment: @user1666620 ah but they are more anxious of not being in control of where you are than you *should* be :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Schedule a meeting with the development manager, apologise for overlooking the fact she is hiring and discuss the positions she is hiring for. Ask what she is *really* looking for, and work out whether you fit the bill. If you do, then that is your opportunity to sell yourself into one of the open roles.

Do you report directly to the development manager? If not, and you feel your immediate manager would put in a good word for you, ask them if they would be prepared to recommend you for another role within the business.

Ultimately, you should be trying to work out whether it was the *role* you decided to leave or both the *role and the organisation*. If the latter, then you are better moving on to a new company.