# Appointment letter salary

Tags: professionalism, salary

I'm a doctor and I recently went for an interview. Afterwards I found I got the job.

I got the appointment letter which stated that my salary will be R68000 and I took the offer but when I went to HR to send in all the necessary documents they now say my salary will be R48000, can that really happen or I'm being ripped off?

Comment: Why does it matter whether "that can really happen"? Either the new offer salary is acceptable to you or it is not. They can't just pull a bait-and-switch and expect you to still accept a job at a 30% lower salary than what they promised. Did you already resign? Did you already start the job or something?

Comment: One of those is presumably a typing mistake or miscommunication (or they're just terrible people or they have some severe financial difficulties). Did they explicitly tell you that the salary is no longer 68k, and is now 48k, or did the documents just say 48k without mentioning 68k? If 68k wasn't mentioned there, you really should just ask them what's up.

Comment: I already started the job and the HR just said my salary will be R48000

Comment: Regardless of what the appointment letter said

Comment: If you're not willing to accept the new salary, express strong disapproval and start looking for another job. Whether you keep working there until you do or whether [you just leave](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16816/why-shouldnt-i-resign-when-i-havent-secured-another-job) is entirely up to you though.

Comment: You could talk to a lawyer on if the appointment letter is legally binding.   Several people should have confirmed the salary on the appointment letter.

Comment: if its formally in the letter its breach of contract talk to a lawyer

Comment: Was the letter written by a doctor? I can never read their handwriting.

Answer (score 3):

Answers here are going to depend on your local laws, so let me try to give a general answer. However don't rely on anything I say being exactly legally true in your jurisdiction.

First thing to do is talk  very strongly to HR. Tell them you expected the higher salary and that the lower is not acceptable. Ask for an explanation of the difference. **Communicate with them in writing**, accept only written replies, and keep copies of every communication.

Unless you want to just give up and accept the low salary, consult a lawyer immediately. They will be able to give you accurate legal information. Everything else I say here is stuff you should confirm with your lawyer.

Start looking for a new job. Unless you accept their terms there is very little chance that this ends well in the long term.

Normally an official offer letter, accepted by you, constitutes a contract. By changing the salary they are breaking the contract, and a lawyer may be able to enforce it, or sue them for the difference. Of course they can always fire you if they like, so enforcing the contract has little long term benefit for you. But until they fire you, a lawyer may be able to get you the original salary.

Another option is simply to walk away from the job. Write and tell them you are disappointed that the original job with the higher salary is not available, and you do not want the job at the lower salary. Do not say that you resign. Treat it as if they had withdrawn the job offer. Check this out with your lawyer.

Finally, tell anyone who will listen who this company is and what they did. If everyone knows about their underhanded tactics, people will stop being caught by them.