# How to ask for a lay off and quit a company without burning bridges

Tags: professionalism, manager, quitting

I have been working in a start-up for over a year now but I am considering quitting the company. There are several reasons, working remotely most of the time and the isolation really pushing me over the edge, pressures from my manager to meet deadlines, constant demands to work over-time and them not being happy with my performance.

I have had anxiety/depression issues before which is hitting me up again because of overthinking about this and some other personal/financial matters in my life. What would you recommend me doing? I would like quit but I do not want to burn bridges behind me (if I needed recommendations, etc.). At the same time this has become a toxic environment which I can no longer tolerate.

Comment: Have to VTC. This is a very personal decision. We cannot make it for you.  If you're seeing a counselor, ask them for some guidance.

Comment: Why would you want to be laid off?

Comment: See also: [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/7149) Also possibly related: [Why shouldn't I resign when I haven't secured another job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/16816)

Comment: If this is software, quitting/hiring/firing **is as exciting as having lunch**.  Just break the news directly and without fuss, "Ah, sorry boss! Bad luck, I've stumbled on to a much better job for me in the blah field, I'll turn in my notice today!"  Say nothing more than that - at all.

Comment: @FrankFYC to get any benefits for voluntary redundancy and possibly to be able to claim social security

Answer (score 0):

Just find another job and quit, especially given your job is taking a toll on your mental health. As long as you honor the standard leaving procedure, i.e. serving your notice period, working during it the same way you would normally work, etc., you should not burn any bridges. In your exit interview, should there be one, don't give them information you think might hurt your relationship.