# Unhappy at work, should I hand in my resignation?

Tags: job-offer, job-change, resignation, notice-period

I am in the process of moving jobs, where I have a conditional offer subject to background checks, where one of the main reasons why I have decided to leave is from not being valued at work.

Without getting too much into the details, there is favouritism prevailing where a certain individual that I do not get along with, is manipulative and using his networking skills to damage my reputation and further his career within the org.

He is going around talking badly about me behind my back to influential people, which is resulting in him being invited to high profile events, whilst I am not.  I feel his end goal is to try to get me to leave, which he has achieved. 
Ironically, my opportunity is with a much more high profile org.

I have escalated this issue several times to Senior management over the past 6 months, but there approach has been to tell me to deal with it directly with him. This particular individual in Senior management also seems to be validating his behaviour by never stepping in but taking his opinions more seriously than mine.

The original plans was to hand in my notice once my offer is unconditional, but I am increasingly becoming frustrated and demotivated at work where I can't stand this anymore since very little of what I say carries any weight anyway.

I appreciate many of you will tell me to wait it out, but is it really worth doing so?

Comment: Very very related: [Why shouldn't I resign when I haven't secured another job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16816/why-shouldnt-i-resign-when-i-havent-secured-another-job)

Comment: Not sure if it does, that individual doesn't have an offer. I actually do.

Comment: ...a conditional offer, which is more like a theory that there may be an offer once conditions are met. Ultimately, you need to weigh the risk of the offer falling apart against the cost of a few days/weeks of frustration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I resign when I haven't secured another job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16816/why-shouldnt-i-resign-when-i-havent-secured-another-job)

Comment: @dwizum sure, that's the only reason why I haven't handed it in yet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *I appreciate many of you will tell me to wait it out, but is it really worth doing so?*

**Yes**, it ***is*** really worth doing so.

What you have now is a **plan** and *plans change*. You have waited this far, why not wait couple more days, to get rid of the problem in a *final* (i.e, deterministic) way?

Assuming the worst case scenario, if the conditional offer is cancelled for some reason, you'll be in the scenario where you already have handed out the notice and not having any standing offer. That will simply *add up* more pressure to the current scenario. Let's avoid getting there, altogether.

Comment: Sure, will give it to the end of the week. Getting really frustrated at the moment.

Comment: @bobo2000 I hope you will wait until the new job offer becomes unconditional and you have a contract. If the background check needs additional information that may be longer than end of the week.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan been nearly 2 weeks already, this is taking ages

Comment: @bobo2000 The fact that this is taking a long time is exactly why you should wait until you have a full offer. What if the process gets delayed another couple weeks? A couple months? What if they pull the offer? How long can you afford to be without a job while you wait?

Comment: @DavidK that is a good point, just pretty unhappy at the moment. :(

Comment: @bobo2000 - Would you rather be paid to be unhappy or be unemployed and unhappy?  You really should wait until you have a firm offer.

Comment: That’s a fair point