# Approved for internal transfer while interviewing externally

Tags: internal-transfer, reputation, multiple-jobs

I'm unhappy with my current position so I applied for an internal transfer as well as some external opportunities. I've been approved for the internal transfer but haven't completed my on-site interviews for the other companies yet. Should I treat my movement internal to the company separate from my moves outside the company and go through with the transfer even if I might then accept an outside offer? This seems like it would burn a bridge with the manager of the new team. I'm not sure what else to do now though. I think I'd be happier with another company, even if I could change teams, but I wouldn't want to back out of the transfer without having an offer from another company.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I resign when I haven't secured another job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16816/why-shouldnt-i-resign-when-i-havent-secured-another-job)

Answer (score 5):

> Should I treat my movement internal to the company separate from my
>   moves outside the company and go through with the transfer even if I
>   might then accept an outside offer?

Yes.

You are still interviewing. You haven't yet accepted an offer. It appears you haven't even received any offers.

You don't know how long it might take, nor if it will even happen. You might find the new department more to your liking and cancel your interview plans.

Go through with the transfer.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I appreciate your answers in this community!

Comment: yup, default position is "it is not real, until you have signed job offer letter"

Comment: I would add, you should tell your outside prospective employers you already have one opportunity, "and they really want me to accept by xxxx date." Nothing like a little competition to move the process forward.