# Should I quit my job whilst looking to a new one?

Tags: acquisition

My current work that I am working has been aqcuisitioned by another company. Suddenly I feel that the company has been invaded and I will have to follow a new process. I mean I feel like that I work somewhere that I choose not to work. Also, refering to us with a special term  I feel like company wants to own me as well (assuming that the company that ackquisitions the one that I currently work is named hypothetically `MamMam`, they are referring tho their employees as `mamamians`).

Also I do not like enforcing me trainings for various reasons though some of them do make sense.

Therefore, I am in a process of looking for a new job. At the same time, my current employer asked me for a CV. I feel like that I do not work any second for the new company. Also, the code quality has been dropped drastically, and I got tired to see bad code all the time.

I live with my parents and I have summed up a good ammount of money that wont cause me poverty issues (though I am not a millionaire). Should I quit yesterday?

Comment: "Should I?" is not a meaningfully answerable question for strangers on the internet.

Comment: This Q and A could be useful: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16816/why-shouldnt-i-resign-when-i-havent-secured-another-job

Answer (score 3):

While is seems like your mind is made up, you are going. There are still may unknowns. I have seen some of the changes you are worried about take days, weeks, months, or even years to take place.

One part of some mergers, is to cut costs. That means jobs. While we have no idea if this is the goal, we also don't know how your position will be evaluated.

I have seen cuts immediately. I have seen bonuses to leave. I have seen bonuses to stay. Putting in your notice before knowing which side your position will fall on, eliminates you from their calculus.

In some countries quitting vs being laid off, can make a difference in post-employment benefits.

You have to decide between what you expect to happen, and what might happen, and how long it will take to find a job.

Answer (score 2):

If you’ve *definitely* made up your mind that you want to leave, the answer to your question is really which of these is the least unpleasant to you:

- having to continue working at your existing employer while you look for a new job
- having no income while you look for a new job

If you choose the first option, don’t resign until you’ve got a signed contract in your hand for a new job.

If you choose the second option, quit now and enjoy your freedom while you job-hunt.

That’s very much going to be a personal decision based on your specific circumstances - you’re unlikely to get a truly objective answer to your question here.

Maybe discuss your options with some close friends or family who have a lot more context for your decision - sometimes just talking things out with someone can help you make your own mind up anyway…

Comment: This answer doesn't consider whether having no current job might affect your attractiveness to potential employers — I suspect many employers treat unemployment as a black mark, if not a red flag. (That's probably one reason why I've seen many recommendations on this site _not_ to quit your current job until you have a signed offer for the next.)

Comment: @gidds - depends how you sell it to the recruiter / in the interview. If you say something like “I wanted a couple of months off to recharge before looking for new challenges” or “I wanted to focus properly on job searching without trying to meet work commitments as well” or any similar positive spins. As a contractor for 20 years I often took 1 month+ breaks between roles and I don’t feel it ever held me back from my choice of work, but ymmv for sure…

Comment: And the biggest reason (imho) for the golden rule of “don’t quit without a new job in place” is that it might unexpectedly take longer than you think to find a role, and not everyone is in a financial position to be able to cope with that, so getting paid for a job you hate while you search for another one is sometimes preferable to no job at all for an extended period

Comment: Perhaps it's different for contractors, as compared to permanent staff? And being able to sell it depends upon getting as far as talking to a recruiter or interviewer — which may be significantly less likely.

Comment: Yeah, that’s all a possibility. There’s no *right* answer to the OP’s question as it depends heavily on their personal circumstances, which only they know…

Comment: My personal approach to job hunting has always been to bypass the application process and try to call the recruiter who is advertising the role to discuss it and see whether it’s a good fit for my experience - I can’t recall ever sending a CV in  stone cold, but again that’s just personal experience, not a set of rules to live by :-).

Answer (score 2):

> Should I quit yesterday?

Personally, I wouldn't. Not because of financial concerns (you look fine there) but as a personal growth opportunity. Changes like this are very common in the workplace. Department shuffles, strategic changes, reorganizations etc. happen fairly regularly. The earlier you learn how to deal with that, the better. "Quit" may be the right answer in some cases, but it should more a matter of last resort otherwise you'll be doing a LOT of job hopping.

So switch your focus from "this all sucks" to "what can I learn here". Observe how different people react and what appears to be working and what doesn't. Observe what transition activities the new company is doing and assess their effectiveness. If you have an idea how to improve it and don't be shy to suggest it to management.

Dial down you emotional gut response (which is normal, but not helpful) and try actively look for positives. If you see some peers that seem to be doing well with the change, take them out for beer or coffee and discuss with them. It's quite possible that they have found something good that you have overlooked.

It's also possible that finding a new job is indeed your best choice and you definitely should be looking. However you can't make an informed decision until you have a) given the new situation and honest try and b) have a new job lined up that you can compare to.

Comment: It is not this sucks it is because I feel like when I try to gime something more I get shot down. Also the code is a spaghetti mess and a simple feature to doi becomes a nightmare. I had to completly write the nessesary documentation because none was provided. How on earth I am supposed to evolve if I get shot down? Why just not make my own business and evolve by myself?